# Updating CentOS by YUM command without removing previous version

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, yum

I want to update my system by yum command, after executing `yum update` it wants to update kernel to **2.6.32-431.5.1.el6** version also it wants to remove my oldest kernel version (2.6.32-279.el6).

**Question:** How to prevent YUM from removing my previous kernel versions?

Comment: first result on duckduckgo https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/37532/how-to-tell-yum-to-keep-an-old-kernel-when-updating-the-kernel/ or even https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/10317/how-to-keep-a-specific-older-kernel-after-yum-update/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done with `yumdb set installonly keep kernel-2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64` command.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `yum` leaves three kernel versions around, and has safeguards against removing the running kernel (and a few other critical system components).